# Unicode for Marlett Font

Tags: html, unicode, cross-browser

I am changing one of the html page which is using **marlett font** like this

```
<td width="33%" style="text-align:right;font:bold 10pt marlett;color:#FFFFFF;vertical-align:middle;">v</td>
```

it is using **marlett font** which is working only for IE.

i am looking for a unicode equivalent for character **"v"**

which is looking like this in IE [image]

Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

The [Marlett](http://www.reactos.org/wiki/Marlett_Characters) font is a collection of icons placed in positions for letters and other common characters. Most of the icons have not been coded as characters at all. The specific character mentioned is somewhat similar to characters in the [Miscellaneous Technical](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/block/Miscellaneous_Technical) block and would probably appear there if it had been coded.

The practical choice is to use an image, in suitably large size and scaled down to match font size, e.g. `<img src=foo.png alt="Up/down" style="height: 0.8em">`.

Answer (score 2):

the unicode equivalent is

```
F076
```

[image: Screenshot from Adobe InDesign]

You have to be sure the visitors of your page have access to the [Marlett Font](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/font.aspx?FMID=1047).

[image: CSS/HTML Code]

Comment: Adobe Illustrator and InDesign persist in saying it is ;-)